# What/Which towns do we go through on the way?

Tags: word-choice, difference

What is the difference between "what" and "which" here? Which one do we prefer? Do they mean the same?

1. **What** towns do we go through on the way?
2. **Which** towns do we go through on the way?

Comment: 1. To know the towns passed through: what towns do we go through? 2. To know the towns in a set of possibilities that are passed through: Derby, Taunton, Swindon, and Newport, which [towns] do we go through?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We usually use **which** when we are asking about a fixed or limited number of things, and **what** when we are not.

Often, however, we can use either **which** or **what** with little difference in meaning (like in this case).

> **What** towns do we go through on the way? (the speaker doesn’t know the area)
>
> **Which** towns do we go through on the way? (the speaker knows the area and the towns in it)